# How to transform a CSV column in dataframe to rows

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dataframe with CSVs in language column

```
     Name Language
0       A French,Espanol
1       B Deutsch,English
```

I wish to transform the above dataframe as below

```
    Name Language
0      A French
1      A Espanol
2      B Deutsch
3      B English
```

I tried the below code but couldn't accomplish

```
df=df.join(df.pop('Language').str.extractall(',$')[0] .reset_index(level=1,drop=True) .rename('Language')) .reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Please post text/code, not images. And check out [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hope my question is clear now

Comment: did you try anything? what did not work?

Comment: Yes... I tried the below:-

Comment: df.join(df.pop('Language').str.split(',')[0]
                   .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
                   .rename('Language'))
           .reset_index(drop=True)

Comment: df.join(df.pop('Language').str.extractall(',$')[0]
                   .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
                   .rename('Language'))
           .reset_index(drop=True)

Comment: always add code, data and error message in question, not in comment. It will be more readable and more people will see it.

Comment: Yes added the code in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pandas.DataFrame.explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) should be suited for that task. Combine it with [pandas.DataFrame.assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to get the desired column:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['A', 'B'], 'Language': ['French,Espanol', 'Deutsch,English']})

df = df.assign(Language=df['Language'].str.split(',')).explode('Language')

#   Name Language
# 0    A   French
# 0    A  Espanol
# 1    B  Deutsch
# 1    B  English
```

Comment: Awesome Thanks a ton       :)

Answer (score 1):

First create a new dataframe with the same columns, then split second values and appent rows to the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

csv_df  = pd.DataFrame([['1', '2,3'], ['2', '4,5']], columns=['Name', 'Language'])
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name ', 'Language'])

for index, row in csv_df .iterrows():
    name = row['Name']
    s = row['Language']
    txt = s.split(',')
    for x in txt:
        df = df.append(pd.Series([name, x], index=df.columns), ignore_index=True)

print(df)
```